# postgresql very slow query

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables : `customer_assortment` and `assortment_product`. They are connected between them with an `assortment_uuid`. I also have:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX assortment_product_assortment_uuid_article_number_idx 
   ON public.assortment_product USING btree (assortment_uuid, article_number) 


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customer_assortment_assortment_uuid_published_to_idx 
   ON public.customer_assortment USING btree (assortment_uuid, published_to)


CREATE INDEX assortment_product_article_number_idx 
   ON public.assortment_product USING btree (article_number)
```

Having a list of customers and a list or articles, I want to get the entries where these 3 things match:

```
- assortment_uuid
- published_to (customer)
- article_number
```

My query looks like this:

```
select 
  ass_product.article_number as articleNumber,
  cust_assortment.published_to as customerId,
  array_agg(cast (cust_assortment.assortment_uuid as varchar) order by cust_assortment.id) as uuids,
  array_agg(cust_assortment.assortment_name order by cust_assortment.id) as names
  from customer_assortment cust_assortment
  join assortment_product ass_product on cust_assortment.assortment_uuid = ass_product.assortment_uuid

  # there are max 10 values here 
  where cust_assortment.published_to = any(values ('7000014910'), ('7000014940') ... )

  # there a max 2000 values here
  and ass_product.article_number = any(values ('FK5327'),('GG1114') ... )

  group by ass_product.article_number, cust_assortment.published_to;
```

This takes tens of seconds to get.

---

My understanding of a query plan is somehow limited, but if it helps, here it is:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=92861.99..94421.60 rows=47988 width=81) (actual time=4107.602..4382.830 rows=20000 loops=1)                                                                                                           |
  Group Key: ass_product.article_number, cust_assortment.published_to                                                                                                                                                       |
  ->  Sort  (cost=92861.99..92981.96 rows=47988 width=61) (actual time=4107.518..4123.623 rows=153760 loops=1)                                                                                                              |
        Sort Key: ass_product.article_number, cust_assortment.published_to                                                                                                                                                  |
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27767kB                                                                                                                                                                             |
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=30.99..89130.83 rows=47988 width=61) (actual time=2.175..3632.692 rows=153760 loops=1)                                                                                                       |
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=30.00..32.00 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=2.090..3.603 rows=2000 loops=1)                                                                                                         |
                    Group Key: "*VALUES*_1".column1                                                                                                                                                                         |
                    ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*_1"  (cost=0.00..25.00 rows=2000 width=32) (actual time=0.004..1.048 rows=2000 loops=1)                                                                                     |
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..445.39 rows=10 width=61) (actual time=0.034..1.797 rows=77 loops=2000)                                                                                                           |
                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.15..0.25 rows=10 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.006 rows=10 loops=2000)                                                                                                     |
                          Group Key: "*VALUES*".column1                                                                                                                                                                     |
                          ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.12 rows=10 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.006 rows=10 loops=1)                                                                                      |
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..44.34 rows=17 width=61) (actual time=0.031..0.176 rows=8 loops=20000)                                                                                                      |
                          ->  Index Scan using assortment_product_article_number_idx on assortment_product ass_product  (cost=0.29..10.01 rows=4 width=22) (actual time=0.013..0.021 rows=10 loops=20000)                   |
                                Index Cond: ((article_number)::text = "*VALUES*_1".column1)                                                                                                                                 |
                          ->  Index Scan using customer_assortment_assortment_uuid_published_to_idx on customer_assortment cust_assortment  (cost=0.55..8.57 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=1 loops=195740)|
                                Index Cond: ((assortment_uuid = ass_product.assortment_uuid) AND ((published_to)::text = "*VALUES*".column1))                                                                               |
Planning time: 3.601 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
Execution time: 4385.493 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
```

Can anybody bring some sanity into my life please?

Comment: That shows under 5 seconds, not tens of seconds.

Comment: What version? It seems pretty old based on the bad VALUES estimate, maybe upgrading will give better performance here

Comment: It seems that there's something a bit iffy here - the cardinalities aren't that high - I woudn't expect 4.4s for a query like that! What's your hardware? CPU, RAM, and especially HDD?

Comment: @jjanes its 5 seconds for `explain analyze`, this is how the query was run and thus the 5 seconds. This is running against amazon RDS, `select version();` says its `PostgreSQL 10.18`

Comment: @Vérace I can't see the HDD for this, but there are 62GB RAM and 8 vCPUs

Comment: Run ` cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational` if its 1, then it's a HDD, if 0 then an SSD! But I imagine with 62GB of RAM and 8 vCPU's, I'd be very surprised if it was a HDD. With a machine of that power, I'm all the more surprised at the poor performance of that query!

Comment: @Vérace exactly, thus my question here. I can run locally that query with far less resources and get under 500 ms response (cries_internally)

Comment: The choice of nested loops seems rather strange for such a higher number of rows (and the nested loops are the major culprit for the long execution time). I would have expected a hash join here. What is the value of `work_mem` and `random_page_cost`? The estimates aren't exactly good either. Does running `analyze` for all involved tables change anything?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name both `work_mem` and `random_page_cost` shows not being set at all in the AWS dashboard, but I assume I can play with those with `set local...` if needed. As to " for all involved tables change anything", I kind of am in the blur :( doesn't `explain analyze  select...` already does this?

Comment: No `explain (analyze)` only _runs_ the statement - as opposed to a "plain" `explain`. `analyze cust_assortment` will update the statistics stored for that table. You should be able to display the values of a configuration parameter using `show work_mem`

Comment: Yes, I know if takes 5 seconds.  But you say it takes tens of seconds.  If it is something *else* which takes 10s of seconds, then you need to tell us what that something else is.

Comment: Where are the max 2000 values coming from for your `article_number` filter? Surely this is not someone manually typing in / ticking boxes in an app? How useful are these values to filtering this join? You might be better off doing 10 nested loops then filtering rather than 10*2000 nested loops

Comment: @AndrewSayer how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get better performance with an index-only scan on `customer_assortment`. For that, create the index as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customer_assortment_assortment_uuid_published_to_idx 
   ON public.customer_assortment (assortment_uuid, published_to)
   INCLUDE (id, assortment_name);
```

Then, make sure the visibility map is up to date:

```
VACUUM public.customer_assortment;
```

Comment: `include` is not supported in 10.18 :( is there any other way I can try?

Comment: @eugene just build a index on `(assortment_uuid, published_to, id, assortment_name)`.  Without USING, you will have to keep the unique index as well.  Or you could upgrade, there are now two things we know of which you are suffering from due to the old version.

Comment: @eugene I meant to say 'Without INCLUDE...' of course

Comment: @jjanes that indeed has helped. What if I select one more field from `customer_assortment`? For example "sales_organization", so my query looks like: `... cust_assortment.published_to as customerId, cust_assortment.sales_organization as sales_organization ... where sales_organization IN <some_values_here>`. There is a separate index for this `sales_organization`, but in my understanding this should be part of the INCLUDE part. I am correct? thank you

Comment: All columns required by the query would have to be in the same single index.